# Use Dlookup inside SQL in VBA for Microsoft Access causes Unknown Error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to update a field based on a lookup field in VBA.  This is the code that I have:

```
SQL = "UPDATE tblDispatch td " & _
      "SET td.NumOfStops = Dlookup(""NumOfStops"", ""qryStops"", ""PK = td.PK"")" & _
      "WHERE td.DispatchDate = #" & Me.tbDate.Value & "#;"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

The syntax and everything looks correct but it keeps giving me a weird error.  "Run-time error '2741' Unknown"  What is this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the datatype of `PK`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess based on the limited information available, but try:

```
SQL = "UPDATE tblDispatch td " & _
      "SET td.NumOfStops = Dlookup(""NumOfStops"", ""qryStops"", ""PK = '"" & td.PK & ""'"") " & _
      "WHERE td.DispatchDate = #" & Me.tbDate.Value & "#;"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

Or if `PK` isn't a string, then:

```
SQL = "UPDATE tblDispatch td " & _
      "SET td.NumOfStops = Dlookup(""NumOfStops"", ""qryStops"", ""PK = "" & td.PK) " & _
      "WHERE td.DispatchDate = #" & Me.tbDate.Value & "#;"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

Comment: That worked; I would have probably figured that out with a better error message. Thank you